# SimpleDateFormat parse resets hours and minutes

Tags: java, android, date, time, simpledateformat

I get a date as String like `"start_date": "2013-07-05T11:32:00+00:00"` and need a date object, which represents it with hours and minutes.

If I use the format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+HH:mm"` and `sdf.parse(startDate)` , in the returned date object the hours and minutes are resetted.

But I need also hours and minutes for date comparison. How can I workaround this problem ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need the pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"` to parse your date. (`"XXX"` stands for the `timezone`)

In your case the second `"HH:mm"` is resetting the values and using the last parsed data.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Perfekt answer, I wish I could lift the answer up :).

Comment: @Luser_k Simply Accept the answer. Then it will stay on top and gives me some reputation.

Answer (score 2):

This part is the problem : `+HH:mm`. You tell the parser that the part after the + sign is the hour and minutes part of the date, and these values are 00 and 00, so you get 0 and 0 as a result. The part startring at the + sign is in fact an offset to UTC time, and the symbol for that is `XXX` (since Java 7).